# Cannot paste a large chunk of LaTeX to Overleaf

Tags: errors, overleaf, bugs

When I try to paste a large chunk of LaTeX to Overleaf (especially tables), nothing happens. Overleaf does not paste my LaTeX to its editor.
I have to manually copy each line in order for Overleaf to accept my "paste" command. I contacted them and report the bugs but so far, after months of waiting, I received no response whatsoever.

How can you paste a large chunk of LaTeX to Overleaf? Why did it happen?

Comment: I have no problem pasting 5,000 lines in Overleaf. Are you sure you contacted their help desk correctly? Usually, they reply at once.

Comment: I used to work normally on Overleaf too, copying and pasting thousand lines to Overleaf without trouble. But recently, every time I try to do this, especially when I try to copy an entire table, Overleaf will prevent me to paste it. It is definitely a very frustrating experience. Anyway, I just hope there will be some solution to this. I tried to report the bug (Menu -> Contact Us), yet, still get no response.

Comment: @Kyle Have you tried using a different browser or a different computer altogether to find out if it's a problem with your setup or in general?

Comment: Hi! I've tried to use Opera, Firefox, Chrome, the problem is still there. I hope to see someone else having the same issue as mine. I just found out that the problem appears when I try to copy and paste any Table-like environment (from begin to end), such as algorithm, table, table*.

Comment: I have just copied 3,000 lines with many tables inside, and I have no problems. Could you please add to your post an example of code you can't paste?

Comment: I'm using PC. Anyway, after months of searching for a solution. My colleague, whom I just met, tell me to Disable Code Check. It works like charms now. 
If you enable Code Check, you cannot COPY and PASTE a large chunk of LaTex.

Comment: @Kyle You could answer your own question, it could be useful for other users.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I've already updated the solution to my question.

Comment: @Kyle I added an answer because the question should be answered in a different post.

Answer (score 2):

The OP found the solution themselves.

Disabling code check solves the issue.

When the document is open: `Menu` --> `Code check` --> `Off`:

[image]

(I write this answer as Community Wiki just to not leave the question unanswered).

Comment: Sadly, it happens again. And this time, turning off Code Check does not work anymore.

Comment: @Kyle Sorry but I think you should contact Overleaf's Help Desk ("Help" button and "Contact us" choice).

Comment: Yes, I contacted them but there is no response. I guess I'll just be patient and try pasting smaller chunks for now.

Comment: @Kyle It's very strange you didn't have an answer. Every time I asked they answered immediately. Are you sure to have asked in the correct way?